# Best practice for using interface functions in the contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, erc-20, decentralized-exchange

I'm developing a DEX contract and trying to figure out what is the best way to use Solidity Interfaces. I did some research and found out there's multiple ways of using interfaces in smart contracts and wondering which one is better and should be used for a DEX contract.

So the first way of using interfaces is calling them by name and passing value
for example I use this code to deposit tokens from other contracts

```
IBEP20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
```

Then I found out there's another way to use interface functions which is like this

```
IBEP20 BEP20;

//I don't know how can I call other contracts in this method
BEP20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
```

And the last method is to import all interface functions inside contract and then overriding all of them

```
contract DEX is IBEP20
```

Now my questions is, Which one of this methods is better and how can I call other contracts with 2nd & 3rd method?

Comment: I suggest to learn from the pros: https://github.com/AugurProject/turbo/tree/dev/packages/smart/contracts , https://github.com/AugurProject/augur/tree/dev/packages/augur-core/src/contracts, that's enough source code base to learn how to use Interfaces

Comment: Good resource but too complicated for my needs

Comment: the examples you are providing will convert to a `CALL` instruction to another contract anyway, so, it doesn't matter how you call another contract, it will be converted to this function in Golang: `func (evm *EVM) Call(caller ContractRef, addr common.Address, input []byte, gas uint64, value *big.Int)`

Comment: So doesn't matter which one I use?

Comment: both will be stored as address internally, but the compiler might add some execution rules. that will depend on the compiler